# Pandas python - Find the minimum timedelta of each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to find the min timedelta of each group.
For example, I have the following data set:

```
DataSet
Name   TimeFromStart
Omri        442 days
Omri        480 days
Omri        443 days
Lior        115 days
Lior        80 days
Lior        0 days


Output:
Name        MinTimeDelta:
Omri        1
Lior        35
```

I assume there is a neat and clean way to do this through groupby with pandas but unfortunately I didn't manage to find how to do this with groupby.

Answer (score 1):

First sorting both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then use custom lambda functio with [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and `min`, convert to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) ad last `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['Name','TimeFromStart'])
         .groupby('Name')['TimeFromStart']
         .apply(lambda x: x.diff().min())
         .dt.days
         .reset_index(name='MinTimeDelta'))
print (df1)
   Name  MinTimeDelta
0  Lior            35
1  Omri             1
```